# Expanding tuples in list comprehension generator

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I am using this function

```
def convert_tuple(self, listobj, fields=['start', 'end', 'user']):
    return [(getattr(obj, field) for  field in fields)
            for obj in listobj]
```

My desired output which I want should be

```
[('2am', '5am', 'john'), ('3am', '5am', 'john1'), ('3am', '5am', 'john2') ]
```

The output of above function is

```
[genexp, genexp, genexp]
```

Its generator expression and I was not able to expand it like I wanted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typecast the gen-exp to a `tuple`

```
def convert_tuple(self, listobj, fields=['start', 'end', 'user']):
    return [tuple(getattr(obj, field) for  field in fields)
            for obj in listobj]
```

Answer (score 5):

The parens are creating a generator expression call tuple as per [Bhargav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551962/2141635) or you can use `operator.attrgetter` with map:

```
from operator import attrgetter
def convert_tuple(listobj, fields=['start', 'end', 'user']):
    return list(map(attrgetter(*fields), listobj)) # python2 just map
```

Demo:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
        self.z = 3


f = Foo()
f2 = Foo()
f2.x = 10


print(convert_tuple([f,f2]))

[(1, 2, 3), (10, 2, 3)]
```

You can remove the list call for python2.